# Is there a way to create a composition entirely from code in Adobe After Effects?

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I'm currently making some infographics for a video in Adobe After Effects, and while I am able to get the kinds of graphs and charts I like using the GUI, I would really prefer to just write up my compositions in code. I've been looking around however and it looks like you can write code in After Effects, but the workflow is a mix of coding and the GUI. What I'd like is to write a text file in javascript (or whatever language is best), and then import and run that javascript to construct a composition, create layers, parent them, set value inheritance, all of that without having to use the GUI. Is this possible?